# 301 not being detected in my file

Tags: php, .htaccess

Im having a problem with my 301 not being detected in my file, almost like the code isnt there Im tryin to have everything using this path mysite.com/page redirected to mysite.com/blog and ive put it in different areas of the file but no luck

this is my code, am i doing something wrong?

```
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9]*)/$ /blog/$1 [NC]
```

and you can see my code here on line 68
http://pastebin.com/tvaXbLxw

Comment: By chance, is there a directory called `page`?

Comment: yes, and it has other subpost under it like page/cake and page/balloon

Comment: It's not the cause of your problem, but you probably want to use `[A-Za-z0-9-]*` (notice the extra `-`).

Comment: no its a example sub directory

Comment: i tried the extra dash and still the same result

Comment: Which URL are you trying to redirect -- please provide an example (from URL => to URL). From what I see from comments -- your rule is a bit incorrect, but I need to be sure.

Comment: im trying to redirect everything from mysite.com/blue to mysite.com/red anything that has blue needs to be redirected to red for example mysite.com/blue/cuppycake would be redirected to mysite.com/red/cuppycake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `RewriteRule` expects a trailing slash. If your URL is like:

```
http://server.com/page/foo/
```

... it will work, while this:

```
http://server.com/page/foo
```

... will not. Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^page/?([A-Za-z0-9]*)/?$ /blog/$1 [NC]
```

It will match against any of those URLs:

```
http://server.com/page
http://server.com/page/
http://server.com/page/foo
http://server.com/page/foo/
```

Note: You may want to use the `L` flag as well:

```
RewriteRule ^page/?([A-Za-z0-9]*)/?$ /blog/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite using `RewriteEngine`?

Comment: Have you set `AllowOverride` with `FileInfo`?